# it seems disable_irq can't really mask the interrupt

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel

It seems in my code disable_irq can't really disable the irq, i have follwoing code

```
rc  = devm_request_threaded_irq(&client->dev, irq, NULL, 
        name_for_ask_question_irq_handler,
        IRQF_ONESHOT | IRQF_TRIGGER_FALLING, client->name, data);
if (rc < 0) {
    dev_err(&client->dev, "request irq failed \n");
    return rc;
}

/* IRQ handler threadeded, this can (and will) sleep */
static irqreturn_t name_for_ask_question_irq_handler(int irq, void *dev)
{
    struct touch_point_data *pdata = dev;

    dev_err(&pdata->client->dev, "%s:%d irq handler \n", __func__, __LINE__);

    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}

static ssize_t wakeup_i2c_store(struct device *dev,
                struct device_attribute *attr,
                const char *buf, size_t size)
{
    struct touch_point_data *pdata = dev_get_drvdata(dev);

    if (buf[0] == '1') {
        disable_irq(pdata->client->irq);
        gpiod_direction_output(pdata->gpiod_irq, 0);
        udelay(100);
        gpiod_direction_output(pdata->gpiod_irq, 1);
        udelay(100);
        gpiod_direction_output(pdata->gpiod_irq, 0);
        udelay(100);
        gpiod_direction_output(pdata->gpiod_irq, 1);
        udelay(100);
        gpiod_direction_input(pdata->gpiod_irq);
        dev_err(&pdata->client->dev, "%s:%d disable irq \n", __func__, __LINE__);
    } else if (buf[0] == '2') {
        enable_irq(pdata->client->irq);
        dev_err(&pdata->client->dev, "%s:%d enable irq \n", __func__, __LINE__);
    }

    return size;
}
```

[and then i get following result:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8u9z.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bVEi2.png)

i am confused, why disable_irq can't really mask the interrupt, it seems this funtion only delay the IRQ, and the irq_handler will still be called after enable_irq.
Is there anyone know what happened?

Comment: Since your device provides an interrupt as wake source, the mechanism in kernel replays interrupt after system resumed.

Answer (score 0):

Delaying the interrupt from being handled until re-enabled is exactly what "masking" an interrupt means.  That's precisely how `disable_irq()` / `enable_irq()` are supposed to work.

If you want to ignore some interrupts, just put that logic in your interrupt handler.

Comment: i really don't want to do that logic in my isr, is there any other API which can really disable the irq, not just "delay" the IRQ.

Comment: @patrick You could program your hardware device not to raise the interrupt to begin with.

Comment: i found this "delayed' feature is designed in kernel/irq/resend.c, and i can disable macro CONFIG_HARDIRQS_SW_RESEND to disable this feature, and thie feature only affect on edge trigger, but if i disable the macro CONFIG_HARDIRQS_SW_RESEND, it maybe also affect some other driver which may need this, it is strange kernel doesn't have some irq_flags to disable this feature separately by each driver who didn't need this.

Comment: @patrick, here, for example, the summary why it might be needed. https://www.linux-mips.org/archives/linux-mips/2017-05/msg00155.html
So, you may not disable it for sure, if you don't know what you are doing explicitly.

Comment: @caf, no, you are wrong, masking IRQ means "I don't want to receive IRQs till further notice". For example, for Edge type of IRQs it means losses of them, for Level type depends on the hardware behaviour.